# Downlaod 32 or 64 bit for Eclipse Kepler and Java SE

Tags: java, eclipse

I am fairly new Java program. My working machine is Windows 7 64 bits. I don't know my client run 32 bits or 64 bit. I am going to download Eclipse Kepler Sr2 Packages and Java SE Development Kit. Do I download 32 or 64 bit to create my project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are unsure what your clients use, it's always safer to choose for 32 bits, since x32 programs also run on x64 systems (and not visa-versa).

Comment: It also depends on the JRE available.

Comment: I don't assume there will be a 64 bit JRE on a 32 bit system?

Comment: No, that's impossible. But the other way around is.

Comment: Thus making the 32 bit version the safer call..? Since your 64 bit application won't run on a 64 bit system with 32 bit JRE installed. My apologies if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini How is this not an attempt to answer the question? He's not asking for clarification, he's making a specific recommendation.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini How does recommending 32 bit for it being "a safe call" not answer the question "Should I use 32 or 64 bit?" ?

Comment: Okay, after re-reading the question I retracted my vote to delete.

Answer (score 2):

I'd get the 64-bit version. Your client's version is largely immaterial, although it might matter if your application includes an Applet or is stand-alone. But, that's a deployment concern and not a development concern (Windows, Linux or Mac - Java is "Write Once, Run Anywhere"<sup>1</sup>).

<sup>1</sup> Very nearly anyway.

Comment: The only case where it should make any difference is if the OP's  application included native code libraries.  Then he would need to be able to reproduce the client's application platform to test; i.e. hardware family + addressing and operating system + version.

Comment: @StephenC Very nearly true. There are some possible issues with GUI layout (try and put something in the bottom left hand corner - or maybe it was right hand - on a mac); Also, there are file system differences (rare... but Windows files are not case-sensitive). I think there might be another corner case or two, but **very nearly** write once, run anywhere!

Comment: That is true, but I'm thinking more on the 32 vs 64 bit issue.  Differences in Mac vs Windows vs Linux shouldn't be relevant there ... assuming that the appropriate platform-specific native libraries are available.  But the availability of those libraries could be the key, and a key reason why you need to be able to reproduce the client's platform.  (Obviously, not the only one.)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you are using 32bit or 64bit version of eclipse, as that is for your development. Regarding the java SE version, you may want to test your final code against the same environment as your client (specially to check if using native APIs). It will be prudent if you can find out which version your client has and test your code at least once against that before final release.